# Fade in and out to happen simultaneously on page

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery animate function that fades two div's in and out on mouse hover / exit.

However, I need to execute the fade in and out simultaneously - currently the first div fades in, then the second div fades out - I need the two happening at the same time. Current code below:

```
var showElements = function(){
    $('#hover-advanced').animate({opacity: "1.0"}, 300),$('#hover-standard').animate({opacity: "0.3"}, 300);

}
```

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks

Comment: Seems to work as intended: http://jsfiddle.net/sveinatle/UDw6u/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

animate() function has a queue option... make it false to have the animations appear as if they are done simultaneously -

```
var showElements = function(){
    $('#hover-advanced').animate({opacity: "1.0"}, {duration: 300, queue: false}),$('#hover-standard').animate({opacity: "0.3"}, {duration: 300, queue: false});
}
```

jQuery animation() documentation - http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: As the animations are for different elements, they have separate queues, so that doesn't make any difference. They look exactly the same: http://jsfiddle.net/7fetn/

Comment: Hi - it did? -  The two divs have background images ... now, with the queue set to false as in your example, the opacity animation looks like it happens simultaneously as required.

Comment: @Marc: Try it without setting the queue property, and see if it really is any difference. Check the fiddle that I posted above, which shows that there is no difference.

Comment: Hi - I have tried as you suggested, and yes - there is a difference! Without queue property, I have the issue where the animates appear one after the other. When I use queue property, the issue is gone and the animations appear simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Your animations *do* run at the same time. They only appear to happen one after the other, because our perception of the opacity is not linear to the value of the opacity. We simply don't see that the element made visible is not fully opaque when the other element has already started to fade.

If you use a much longer animation time, you will see that they actually run simultaneously.

You can try to use the `linear` easing instead of the default `swing` easing, and see if it looks better:

```
$('#hover-advanced').animate({opacity: "1.0"}, 300, "linear");
$('#hover-standard').animate({opacity: "0"}, 300, "linear");
```

Another option is to make the animations *not* run simultaneously. If you add a delay to the animation that is made visible, they will *seem* to run simultaneously:

```
$('#hover-advanced').delay(100).animate({opacity: "1.0"}, 300);
$('#hover-standard').animate({opacity: "0"}, 300);
```